# Typing in exact URL to visit specific partial Angular using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Pretty new to Angular, I am sure I'm missing something obvious here.  I am using ui-router.

I want to provide a link to my clients so that they can click the URL link and visit the web app with the appropriate partial.  I also want to be able to pass in parameters.  Here's how I approached this (kind of hokey).  This is in my main controller:

```
var pNumber = $location.search().number;
    if (!(pNumber == null || pNumber == "")){
        $state.go('view-ticket');
    }
```

Here is my app.js:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: 'partials/welcome-screen.html',
      controller: 'mainPageController'
    })
    .state('submit-ticket', {
      url: "/submit-ticket",
      templateUrl: 'partials/ticket-submit.html',
      controller: 'TicketSystemTestCtrl'      
    })
    .state('view-ticket', {
      url: "/view",
      templateUrl: "partials/ticket-central.html",
      controller: 'TicketCentralCtrl'
    })
```

The logic is this:  If the URL contains a param 'number' inject ticket-central.html partial.

However, when I run this in the debugger, it seems the first part of the code got executed before it loads the welcome-screen.html partial.  How to solve this?

EDIT:  I am trying to type this into the URL:  http://localhost/techsupport/view and I want it to load the ticket-central.html partial into the main view.  However, it won't work.

Comment: I don't understand. When you go to /submit-ticket/number it should load the ticket-central partial instead of ticket-submit?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly all you want to do is to provide a possibility to 'deep-link' to the 'view-ticket' state.

for this search params are not the ideal solution as they are optional, just use path variables:

```
.state('view-ticket', {
  url: '/view/:ticketNumber,
  template: 'partials/ticket-central.html',
  controler: 'TicketCentralCtrl'
})
```

also don't use the $location service if you don't really have to, have a look at $stateParams

here is a small plunkr with a welcome and a ticket state
launch the preview in a separate window to see how the url changes - you can also refresh on each page and the correct state will be loaded

https://plnkr.co/edit/r3UcYbfwET0OVwkd77Rv